# airflow spark-submit operator - No such file or directory: 'spark-submit': 'spark-submit'

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

I am new to airflow and I am trying to schedule a pyspark job in airflow deployed in  docker containers, here is my dag,

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

spark_master = "spark://spark:7077"
spark_app_name = "Spark Hello World"


now = datetime.now()

default_args = {
 "owner": "airflow",
 "depends_on_past": False,
 "start_date": datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day),
 "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
 "email_on_failure": False,
 "email_on_retry": False,
 "retries": 1,
 "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1)
 }

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="spark-test",
    description="This DAG runs a simple Pyspark app.",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(1)
         )

t1 = DummyOperator(task_id="start", dag=dag)

#Task 2 check if file exist
t2 = BashOperator(task_id='check_file_exists', bash_command='shasum 
/usr/local/spark/app/first.py',retries=2, retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=15),dag=dag)

t3 = SparkSubmitOperator(task_id="spark_job", application='/usr/local/spark/app/first.py', 
    name=spark_app_name,
   conn_id="spark_default",
   conf={"spark.master":spark_master},
   dag=dag)


t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

My python script is: *first.py*

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

if __name__ == '__main__':
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)


text_file = sc.textFile("/usr/local/spark/resources/data/Loren.txt")
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
.map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

counts.saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/resources/data/loren_counts_task4")
```

The error I'm getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'spark-submit': 'spark-submit'`

```
Reading local file: /usr/local/airflow/logs/spark-test/spark_job/2021-07- 
09T20:46:19.130980+00:00/2.log
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,119] {{taskinstance.py:655}} INFO - Dependencies all met for 
<TaskInstance: spark-test.spark_job 2021-07-09T20:46:19.130980+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,151] {{taskinstance.py:655}} INFO - Dependencies all met for 
<TaskInstance: spark-test.spark_job 2021-07-09T20:46:19.130980+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,152] {{taskinstance.py:866}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,152] {{taskinstance.py:867}} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 2
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,152] {{taskinstance.py:868}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,165] {{taskinstance.py:887}} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkSubmitOperator): 
spark_job> on 2021-07-09T20:46:19.130980+00:00
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,169] {{standard_task_runner.py:53}} INFO - Started process 19335 to run 
task
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,249] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: 
spark-test.spark_job 2021-07-09T20:46:19.130980+00:00 [running]> 9b6d4f74ee93
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,293] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2021-07-09 20:47:50,292] 
{{base_hook.py:84}} INFO - Using connection to: id: spark_default. Host: yarn, Port: None, 
Schema: None, Login: None, Password: None, extra: XXXXXXXX
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,294] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2021-07-09 20:47:50,294] 
{{spark_submit_hook.py:323}} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master yarn --conf 
spark.master=spark://spark:7077 --name Spark Hello World --queue root.default 
usr/local/spark/app/first.py
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,301] {{taskinstance.py:1128}} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or 
directory: 'spark-submit': 'spark-submit'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in 
_run_raw_task
result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py", line 187, in execute
self._hook.submit(self._application)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py", line 
393, in submit
**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'spark-submit': 'spark-submit'
[2021-07-09 20:47:50,304] {{taskinstance.py:1170}} INFO - All retries failed; marking task as 
FAILED.dag_id=spark-test, task_id=spark_job, execution_date=20210709T204619, 
start_date=20210709T204750, end_date=20210709T204750
[2021-07-09 20:48:00,096] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2021-07-09 20:48:00,095] 
{{local_task_job.py:103}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I ran the spark-submit on the *spark container* and it works perfectly. i am not sure what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You should see this link [Apache Spark and Apache Airflow connection in Docker based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418698/apache-spark-and-apache-airflow-connection-in-docker-based-solution)

From error

```
spark-submit --master yarn --conf 
spark.master=spark://spark:7077 --name Spark Hello World --queue root.default
```

It has to be

```
spark-submit --master spark://spark:7077 --conf 
spark.master=spark://spark:7077 --name Spark Hello World --queue root.default
```

By setting master in extra options in your connections for this spark conn id (spark_default).

Conn Type: Spark    (If there is no spark. You should install apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark in airflow docker.)
Host: spark://spark
port: 7077

I am not sure this is your docker-compose file or not.
https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml

## Second edition

If you want to install the package in a container. You should edit the second line

```
   webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
```

to

```
   webserver:
        build: ./airflow
        restart: always
```

This is an airflow directory.

- airflow

  - Dockerfile
  - requirements.txt

Dockerfile

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN rm -rf requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt

```
apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark == X.X.X (The version which compatible with your airflow version )
```

You can find it here (The version which compatible with your airflow version ).
https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark/

Maybe you should run the command submit-spark to see what is going on and fix the error there(in the container).I hope you can fix it.

Comment: please how do I install apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark from on airflow container from docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml so that when I run the file it installs with it.. I tried installing it on the airflow container but spark did not show among the connections

Comment: I also got this error while installing it     "ERROR: rich 10.5.0 has requirement pygments<3.0.0,>=2.6.0, but you'll have pygments 2.5.2 which is incompatible."

Comment: I just add how to install the python package in a docker container.

Comment: Thanks alot for all your efforts.. however its still giving the same error. I followed your instructions to the letter. my airflow version is : 1.10.9 and I used 1.0.3. Also spark did not show up on the conn type

Comment: if you can recommend a docker image that runs spark and airflow successfully would be glad... this thing is driving me nuts

Comment: try this one(https://github.com/ohmohmpr/airflow-spark-docker-for-github). Put your dag file in airflow/dags, put everything like jars file or python in work directory, and don't forget to set master in extra options in your connections for spark conn id.